# Proving a function in Big O

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Lets say we want to try to show $f(n) \in O(g(n))$, which may or may not be true.

Then by definition we find a large enough $n$ and a constant $k > 0$ such that $|f(n)| \le k|g(n)|$, but lets say $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|f(n)|}{|g(n)|} = \infty$$ what can I conclude from this? That $f(n) \not\in O(g(n))$?

Comment: There is a conflict in your definition.

Comment: @OmG, what is the conflic?

Comment: @Ghar, you are correct: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|f(n)|}{|g(n)|}=\infty$ implies that $f(n)\not\in O(g(n)), n\to\infty$. This is quite straightforward to prove by using the definitions of the limit and the "big O". Do you know how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the statement 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{|f(n)|}{|g(n)|}=\infty
$$
means that for any $M>0$ we can find a large enough $n$ such that 
$$
\frac{|f(n)|}{|g(n)|}>M\implies|f(n)|>M|g(n)|
$$
Can you see why this is a problem for a claim that $f\in O(g)$?

Answer (score 0):

Provided $g(n)\neq 0$ you can divide the big O.

$f(n)=O(g(n))$ means also $\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)}=O(1)$

Being $O(1)$ means $\le k$ for some constant $k$, in other words, it is **bounded**.

Obviously an infinite limit is not bounded, thus $f(n)\notin O(g(n))$